# Spring data - MongoDB: aggregation pipeline updates did not work

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

It's simple example from https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.aggregation-update:

```
Aggregation.newUpdate().set("average").toValue(ArithmeticOperators.valueOf("tests").avg());
```

When I run it the result is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationUpdate.set(AggregationUpdate.java:142) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationUpdate$1.toValue(AggregationUpdate.java:207) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
```

Has anyone tried to use aggregation pipeline updates in spring data?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the spring documentation - a valid example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationUpdate.html